# Connecting to mongodb atlas, behind a firewall?

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble connecting to MongoDB Atlas at work due to what I assume is a firewall issue. I know there's nothing wrong with my code because I was able to get it to work at home, and I set my Network Access to 0.0.0.0/0

I was wondering if there was a way to use Atlas despite this firewall. I can't change any settings on my firewall, and what I can download is very limited. I am open to using another website for a database.

Comment: Atlas uses [TCP ports 27015-27017](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/). Have you confirmed those ports are unreachable from your location? This Port Tester will load if port 27017 is open. http://portquiz.net:27017/

Comment: Yes, the site was unable to load. Firewall blocked access.